# URL "starts with" using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, contains, startswith

Say I have the following url:

> http://example.com/api

How can I create a regex that will match any url *starting with* that url segment above?

For example:

> http://example.com/api/auth (should match)
>
> http://example.com/api/orders (should match)
>
> http://example.com/api/products (should match)
>
> http://example.com/auth (should not match)
>
> http://examples.com/api/auth (should not match)
>
> https://example.com/api/auth (should not match)

Yes, obviously I could just call `string.indexOf(url) == 0` to do a "starts with" check, but I specifically need a regular expression because I have to provide one to a third-party library.

Comment: Try a thing or 2 yourself, first. Then tell us if you have to provide a string, from which a regex will be created (`new RegExp` argument != `/pattern/`)

Answer (score 13):

The `^` modifier at the start of the expression means "string must start with":

```
/^http:\/\/example\.com\/api/
```

If you were using a different language which supports alternative delimiters, then it would probably be worth doing since the URL will contain `/`s in it. This **doesn't work** in Javascript (h/t T.J. Crowder) but does in languages like PHP (just mentioning it for completeness):

```
#^http://example\.com/api#
```

You could use this in JavaScript, though:

```
new RegExp("^http://example\\.com/api")
```

It's also worth noting that this will match `http://example.com/apis-are-for-losers/something`, because you're not testing for a `/` after `api` - just something to bear in mind. To solve that, you can use an alternation at the end requiring either that you be at the end of the string or that the next character be a `/`:

```
/^http:\/\/example\.com\/api(?:$|\/)/

new RegExp("^http://example\\.com/api(?:$|/)")
```

Comment: Ah true, I missed the JS tag :-) I'll bin that one

Comment: Well, you can always use the RegExp constructor and pass a string in, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Very true. That's normally more trouble than it's worth because of the string literal rules, but in this case, it may well be clearest.

Answer (score 4):

Why a regex if your search term is constant?

```
if (str.substr(0, 22) == 'http://example.com/api') console.log('OK');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
^http:\/\/example\.com\/api.*
```

Regex [link](http://regex101.com/r/aA8hI6/1)

Answer (score 2):

Since it's javascript you can try this

```
 var str = "You should match this string that starts with"; 
 var res = str.match(/^You should match.*/);
 alert(res);
```

Comment: You can drop the `.*` bit from your pattern, You're looking for a match for `You should match`, anything that follows the match is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You can use an 'anchor' to match the start (or end) of a string.

More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html